# Does the creation of a post count as an edit for making a post CW?

Tags: support, community-wiki

[What is “context specific”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62085/what-is-context-specific) was edited by [5 different users](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/62085/revisions); one of them just edited the tags, so it doesn't count to make the post CW.

As per [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) does the initial edit make from the author count as edit? Does it count when checking if the author of the post edited the post at least 10 times?

Comment: I've also found that an approved suggested edit that only changes the tags will count towards that 5.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/cw-caused-by-too-many-editors-includes-the-op

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [an answer from Anna Lear on another meta site](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1350/472), the original post did not count.

However, since this question was asked, automatic conversion to community-wiki status based on the number of edits (or editors) [has been turned off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/165773).  Posts now only become community wiki by explicit action.